# Duas conexões BD em um unico arquivo

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, hospedagem

Boa tarde pessoal, gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer duas confiurações ao banco de dados, no caso eu estou com o dreamweaver conectado ao meu site online e gostaria de seguir com ele no localhost também, então queria saber se na conexão sql teria como eu me conectar no localhost e no site?

Comment: não tem como fazer uma condição tipo, se ele estiver em localhost ele usa uma config se tiver no site usa outra?

Comment: Ahhh isso tem como sim.